# Minimalist example of convertion from custom dataset to COCO format with pycococreator

Tags: python, dataset, coco

The aim is to convert a numpy array (2164, 190, 189, 2) containing pairs of grayscaled+groundtruth images to COCO format:

[image: grey+groundtruth (left).]

I tried to generate a minimalist annotation in coco format as follow:

```
from pycococreatortools import pycococreatortools

N = 1
grey = data[N,:,:,0]
labels = data[N,:,:,1]
mask1 = labels == 1
mask2 = labels == 2
mask3 = labels == 3

segmentation_id = "chromosome1_1" 
image_id = "0001"
category_info = "chromosome1"
binary_mask = mask1
image = grey
print(image.size, image.shape)

annotation_info_mask1 = pycococreatortools.create_annotation_info(segmentation_id, image_id, 
                                                              category_info,
                                                              binary_mask,
                                                              image.size, tolerance=2)
```

and I get the following error:

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in ()
>         2                                                                   category_info,
>         3                                                                   binary_mask,
>   ----> 4                                                                   image.size, tolerance=2)
>
> 2 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in resize(self,
>   size, resample, box)    1866             )    1867 
>   -> 1868         size = tuple(size)    1869     1870         if box is None:
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Here image.size is equal to **35910** and image.shape is (190, 189).

It seems that *create_annotation_info()* is waiting a tuple or a list. Is it correct?
What would be the right way to do it?

A draft colab notebook [is here to get the whole dataset.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sC-oqYqv60VrL5yrQqCymkooXEWv-_QD#scrollTo=yNa8XHD6cqW4)